# Cannot write external object inside of custom object to CSV using CSVHelper with ClassMap

Tags: c#, csv, linq, unity-game-engine, csvhelper

I want to write a Vector3 object (see https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.html) which is part of my custom class to a CSV file:

```cs
public class BehaviouralData
{
    public float ActionZ { get; set; }
    public float ActionX { get; set; }
    public int TargetBallAgentHashCode { get; set; }
    public Vector3 TargetBallLocalPosition { get; set; }
    public bool CollectBehaviouralData { get; set; }
    public DateTime ActionTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
}
```

Therefore I am using a ClassMap

```cs
public sealed class Vector3Map : ClassMap<Vector3>
{
    public Vector3Map()
    {
        Map(m => m.x);
        Map(m => m.y);
        Map(m => m.z);
    }
}
```

Which I register before writing to a file:

```cs
...
using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, config))
{
    csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<Vector3Map>();
    csv.WriteRecords(data);
}
...
```

When I try to save the file, I get the following error message:

```
ArgumentException: Incorrect number of arguments supplied for call to method 'Single get_Item(Int32)'
Parameter name: property
System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Property (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression expression, System.Reflection.PropertyInfo property) (at <1e18c5a6594041c9844bfd0b6618ee4a>:0)
CsvHelper.Expressions.ExpressionManager.CreateGetMemberExpression (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression recordExpression, CsvHelper.Configuration.ClassMap mapping, CsvHelper.Configuration.MemberMap memberMap) (at <9a1379e089274cc1baf4edcf480e4c6d>:0)
CsvHelper.Expressions.ExpressionManager.CreateGetMemberExpression (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression recordExpression, CsvHelper.Configuration.ClassMap mapping, CsvHelper.Configuration.MemberMap memberMap) (at <9a1379e089274cc1baf4edcf480e4c6d>:0)
CsvHelper.Expressions.ObjectRecordWriter.CreateWriteDelegate[T] (T record) (at <9a1379e089274cc1baf4edcf480e4c6d>:0)
CsvHelper.Expressions.RecordWriter.GetWriteDelegate[T] (T record) (at <9a1379e089274cc1baf4edcf480e4c6d>:0)
CsvHelper.Expressions.RecordWriter.Write[T] (T record) (at <9a1379e089274cc1baf4edcf480e4c6d>:0)
CsvHelper.Expressions.RecordManager.Write[T] (T record) (at <9a1379e089274cc1baf4edcf480e4c6d>:0)
CsvHelper.CsvWriter.WriteRecords[T] (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] records) (at <9a1379e089274cc1baf4edcf480e4c6d>:0)
Rethrow as WriterException: An unexpected error occurred.
IWriter state:
Row: 2
Index: 0
HeaderRecord:
2
CsvHelper.CsvWriter.WriteRecords[T] (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] records) (at <9a1379e089274cc1baf4edcf480e4c6d>:0)
Util.SaveDataToCSV[T] (System.String path, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] data) (at Assets/Scripts/Util/Util.cs:178)
BehaviourMeasurement.SaveRawBehavioralDataToCSV () (at Assets/Scripts/Measurement/BehaviourMeasurementBehaviour.cs:1021)
BehaviourMeasurementBehaviour.OnDisable () (at Assets/Scripts/Measurement/BehaviourMeasurementBehaviour.cs:122)
```

And the empty CSV file has the following columns:

```
ActionZ,ActionX,TargetBallAgentHashCode,Item,Item,magnitude,sqrMagnitude,magnitude,sqrMagnitude,CollectBehaviouralData,ActionTime,Time
```

As you can see not the coordinates are written to the file but other properties (e.g. `magnitude`) which I do not want to include.
Why does CSVHelper not map the right properties into the CSV file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your basic problem is that, as [derHugo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7111561/derhugo) noted in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76630538/3744182), when CsvHelper automaps a type, it automaps the types of all property values, rather than using any class maps that might have been previously registered for those types.  Specifically in the case of [`Vector3`](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/master/Runtime/Export/Math/Vector3.cs) it automaps its properties instead of the fields `x`, `y` and `z`, eventually leading to a crash.<sup>[1]</sup>.

So, what are your workarounds?  Other than manually mapping the `x`, `y` and `z` fields manually as suggested in derHugo's answer, you have a couple of additional options.

**Firstly**, you could automap your types containing `Vector3` and fix the references afterwards.  To do this, define the following generic `ClassMap<T>` and associated extension methods:

```
public class CustomAutoMap<TClass> : ClassMap<TClass>
{
    // Automaps the given type then fixes up references to Vector3 (if any).
    public CustomAutoMap()
    {
        AutoMap(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        // Now fix the Vector3 references.
        this.UpdateReferences<Vector3Map, Vector3>();
    }
}

public static partial class CsvExtensions
{
    // Update autoampped reference maps to a different map.
    // Note this should only be done within a ClassMap constructor itself.
    public static ClassMap UpdateReferences<TReferenceMap, TReferenceClass>(this ClassMap classMap, params object[] constructorArgs) where TReferenceMap : ClassMap<TReferenceClass>
    {
        // TODO: nested references of references.
        for (int i = 0, count = classMap.ReferenceMaps.Count; i < count; i++)
            if (classMap.ReferenceMaps[i].Data.Member.MemberType() == typeof(TReferenceClass))
                classMap.UpdateReference<TReferenceMap, TReferenceClass>(i, constructorArgs);
        return classMap;
    }
    
    public static MemberReferenceMap UpdateReference<TReferenceMap, TReferenceClass>(this ClassMap classMap, int index, params object[] constructorArgs) where TReferenceMap : ClassMap<TReferenceClass>
    {
        if (index < 0 || index >= classMap.ReferenceMaps.Count)
            throw new ArgumentException(nameof(index));
        var oldRef = classMap.ReferenceMaps[index];
        classMap.ReferenceMaps.RemoveAt(index);
        var newRef = classMap.References(typeof(TReferenceMap), oldRef.Data.Member, constructorArgs);
        if (oldRef.Data.Prefix != null)
            newRef.Prefix(oldRef.Data.Prefix);
        classMap.ReferenceMaps.Swap(index, classMap.ReferenceMaps.IndexOfWithHint(newRef, classMap.ReferenceMaps.Count - 1));
        return newRef;
    }
    
    static Type? MemberType(this MemberInfo m) =>
        m switch
        {
            PropertyInfo p => p.PropertyType,
            FieldInfo f => f.FieldType,
            _ => null,
        };

    static int IndexOfWithHint<T>(this IList<T> list, T item, int hint) where T : class
    {
        if (hint >= 0 && hint < list.Count && list[hint] == item)
            return hint;
        return list.IndexOf(item);
    }
                                    
    static void Swap<T>(this IList<T> list, int i, int j)
    {
        if (i != j)
        {
            T temp = list[i];
            list[i] = list[j];
            list[j] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

And now serialize your `BehaviouralData` as follows:

```
var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, config))
{
    csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<CustomAutoMap<BehaviouralData>>();
    csv.WriteRecords(data);
}
```

Which results in:

```
ActionZ,ActionX,TargetBallAgentHashCode,CollectBehaviouralData,ActionTime,Time,x,y,z
0,0,1,False,01/01/0001 00:00:00,01/01/0001 00:00:00,1.1,1.1,1.1
0,0,2,False,01/01/0001 00:00:00,01/01/0001 00:00:00,2.1,2.1,2.1
0,0,3,False,01/01/0001 00:00:00,01/01/0001 00:00:00,3.1,3.1,3.1
```

If you would like the `x`, `y` and `z` fields to have some prefix, add [`[HeaderPrefix("prefix")]`](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/master/src/CsvHelper/Configuration/Attributes/HeaderPrefixAttribute.cs) to `TargetBallLocalPosition` like so:

```
public class BehaviouralData
{
    [CsvHelper.Configuration.Attributes.HeaderPrefix("TargetBallLocation_")]
    public Vector3 TargetBallLocalPosition { get; set; }
    // Remainder unchanged
```

And you will get instead:

```
ActionZ,ActionX,TargetBallAgentHashCode,CollectBehaviouralData,ActionTime,Time,TargetBallLocation_x,TargetBallLocation_y,TargetBallLocation_z
0,0,1,False,01/01/0001 00:00:00,01/01/0001 00:00:00,1.1,1.1,1.1
0,0,2,False,01/01/0001 00:00:00,01/01/0001 00:00:00,2.1,2.1,2.1
0,0,3,False,01/01/0001 00:00:00,01/01/0001 00:00:00,3.1,3.1,3.1
```

If you need more manual control over the formatting of `BehaviouralData` you will need to create a manual class map.  When you do, use the method [`ClassMap<TClass>.References<TClassMap>(Expression<Func<TClass, object>> expression, params object[])`](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/7b3ed4d45af8385e732a42eb161b0d129736edb3/src/CsvHelper/Configuration/ClassMap%601.cs#L62) rather than `ClassMap<TClass>.Map()` to reference the contents of `Vector3` using your `Vector3Map`:

```
public class BehaviouralDataMapExplicit : ClassMap<BehaviouralData>
{
    public BehaviouralDataMapExplicit()
    {
        Map(m => m.ActionZ);
        Map(m => m.ActionX);
        Map(m => m.TargetBallAgentHashCode);
        References<Vector3Map>(m => m.TargetBallLocalPosition)
            .Prefix("TargetBallLocation_");
        Map(m => m.CollectBehaviouralData);
        Map(m => m.ActionTime);
        Map(m => m.Time);
    }
}
```

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OIyRzx).

---

<sup>[1]</sup> CsvHelper seems to have a bug here.  Specifically, for classes that do not implement `IEnumerable` it attempts to automap **[indexed properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/)**, resulting in the exception you see.  This is a straightforward bug in CsvHelper, it should check that [`PropertyInfo.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getindexparameters) before automapping any property discovered by reflection. But even if CsvHelper fixed this bug, you still wouldn't get what you want, which is the three fields of `Vector3`, not its properties.

Answer (score 2):

I played around a bit in a [.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2yUNmh).

When using an explicit map also for the `BehaviouralData`

```
public class BehaviouralDataMap : ClassMap<BehaviouralData>
{
    public BehaviouralDataMap()
    {
        Map(o => o.ActionZ);
        Map(o => o.ActionX);
        Map(o => o.TargetBallAgentHashCode);
        Map(o => o.TargetBallLocalPosition);
        Map(o => o.CollectBehaviouralData);
        Map(o => o.ActionTime);
        Map(o => o.Time);
    }
}
```

it seemed to be fixed.

When using automapping like

```
public class BehaviouralDataMap : ClassMap<BehaviouralData>
{
    public BehaviouralDataMap()
    {
        AutoMap(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
}
```

which is probably what is going to be used by default anyway - it broke again.

Also tried this but same

```
public class BehaviouralDataMap : ClassMap<BehaviouralData>
{
    public BehaviouralDataMap()
    {
        AutoMap(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        Map(o => o.TargetBallLocalPosition).Ignore();
        Map(o => o.TargetBallLocalPosition.x);
        Map(o => o.TargetBallLocalPosition.y);
        Map(o => o.TargetBallLocalPosition.z);
    }
}
```

---

*Update*

Actually this explicit mapping didn't work either -_-

It only printed `Vector3` into the CSV so the second map seemed to be completely ignored.

Quite hideous but this seems to work

```
public class BehaviouralDataMap : ClassMap<BehaviouralData>
{
    public BehaviouralDataMap()
    {
        Map(o => o.ActionZ);
        Map(o => o.ActionX);
        Map(o => o.TargetBallAgentHashCode);
        Map(o => o.TargetBallLocalPosition.x);
        Map(o => o.TargetBallLocalPosition.y);
        Map(o => o.TargetBallLocalPosition.z);
        Map(o => o.CollectBehaviouralData);
        Map(o => o.ActionTime);
        Map(o => o.Time);
    }
}
```

**BUT** to be honest at least for the writer part this seems extremely explicit and at best would be a workaround.

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping for a more generic solution since I have to use the Vector3 class for more objects. Therefore it would be cool to define the mapping only once (like I tried to do). But if there is no other solution I will stick to your answer.

Comment: @Ling honestly I hope a lot some expert will provide a better way as well ;)